# How to fix "Unable to delete user profile" exception

Tags: 2007, error, user-profile

> MySiteCleanup: Unable to delete user
>   profile (UserX).  Exception:
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.DSInvalidDomainNameException:
>   The format of the specified domain
>   name is invalid. --->
>   System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception:
>   The format of the specified domain
>   name is invalid     --- End of inner
>   exception stack trace ---     at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.DS.ProcessDCWIn32Exception(Int32
>   ret, Int32 win32err)     at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.DS.GetDomainControllerInfo(String
>   strDomain)     at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.DS.GetDCName(String
>   strDomain)     at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.MySiteCleanupJob.IsActiveUser(LDAPConnection
>   connLDAP, String filter, Credentials
>   credentials)     at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.MySiteCleanupJob.IsActiveUser(UserProfile
>   up, UserProfileConfigManager upcm,
>   String searchApplicationName)     at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.MySiteCleanupJob.ProcessPendingDeletion(String
>   username, ServerContext context,
>   UserProfileManager upm,
>   UserProfileConfigManager upcm, String
>   searchApplicationName)

Comment: @Crazy: Please pay attention to the tags you are using and make sure they relate directly to your questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most descriptive part of this message is "**The format of the specified domain name is invalid.**". It looks as it can't find a "my site" for a user. Can you identify for which user it's trying to clean up "my site" (recently deleted or disabled) and see in his/her profile the My Site link. If the link is there and "my site" isn't, that could be one problem.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have serious issues with your installation (considering all your posts here). A couple of questions:

- Have you fiddled with the SharePoint databases?
- Have you changed domain or similar on your SharePoint servers?
- Have you recently installed or changed your SharePoint servers in any way?
- Do you have any warnings or errors in the Windows Event Logs relating to this?